# C# Does an empty lock block get "optimized" away?

Tags: c#, locking, compiler-optimization

I couldn't find any information on whether the C# compiler or JIT will remove a lock statement with no code inside. Will this always generate and execute the `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` calls?

```
lock(lockObj) { }
```

A (drastically simplified) version of what I'm trying to do (yes I know calling a callback in a lock is bad):

```
public class ExecutionSource
{
    private List<Action<object>> _callbacks = new List<Action<object>>();
    private object _value;

    public void AddListener(Action<object> listener)
    {
        object temp = _value;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            listener(temp);
            return;
        }
        lock (_callbacks)
        {
            temp = _value;
            if (temp != null)
            {
                listener(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                _callbacks.Add(listener);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("value must be non-null");
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, value, null) != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can only execute once.");
        }
        lock (_callbacks) { } // Wait for a listener that is currently being added on another thread. No need to lock the entire loop.
        foreach (var callback in _callbacks)
        {
            callback(value);
        }
        _callbacks.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see how it could be "optimized" away as it would massively change the semantics - if another thread already owns the lock (and never releases it) then the empty lock block *should* effectively halt the thread executing it. That said, I don't see how your empty lock block accomplishes what the comment expresses...

Comment: I'll add `lock` does more than it may seem, including a [memory barrier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @JonSkeet It accomplishes what the comment says by `AddListener` locking, then checking the value, while `Execute` sets the value, then locks. If multiple threads are waiting on the lock in `AddListener` when `Execute` is called, only 1 will possibly be adding to the list. When any of the other threads take the lock, they will see the value was already set (thanks to the memory barrier from the lock). Any further calls will never hit the lock... Assuming the value sent into `Execute` is non-null, of course.

Comment: @Tim: No, it doesn't accomplish that - because if nothing already has the lock, it doesn't wait at all. If you create an instance of `ExecutionSource` and call `Execute` (and do nothing else) it will just set `_value` to whatever value was passed, acquire and release the lock, and then execute the empty list of callbacks. It will *not* wait for a listener to be added on another thread, which is what the comment says it will do.

Comment: I meant it will wait for any listeners _currently being added_ (meaning another thread already has the lock in `AddListener`). I don't care if a listener is never added before `Execute` is called. I edited that comment in my question to be more clear.

Comment: Yeah so this is not thread safe to start with. Based on your comment on my answer, you might want to use a `ReaderWriterLock` which will support a single writer and multiple readers.

Comment: @00110001 Thanks for the suggestion for `ReaderWriterLock`. Could you explain what is unsafe about it as is, please?

Comment: `_callbacks.Add(listener);` can add to the collection while `foreach (var callback in _callbacks)` is enumerating

Comment: It shouldn't be able to. That's why there's a second value check inside the lock body. `lock (_callbacks) { }` waits for the one currently running `_callbacks.Add(listener);` if any, then any subsequent lock takes will see the value was set and not add to the list again.

Comment: Although the surface area has minimized, There is nothing from stopping a thread hitting the pseudo lock exiting, starting the enumeration, while another thread enters the listener lock and adds to the collection.... Now if that foreach was inside the lock, that would be completely protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [sharplib](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs7omACsYwGOrghgA1gHk+dALx0AdjADu3PgIwAKAJQBuDl1oMUdALLa2+rlxHiNNyXy1s6AX0uuqLoA===) we can see that compiler do not remove empty lock block. Moreoever, I can't imagine how we can optimize it out in compile-time in real multithreading environment and be sure that we do not broke anything.

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not. The CLI cannot assume there is no other thread already locking over the object.

The object header or sync block table will still get marked with the Thread ID and a non zero recursion count on `Monitor.Enter/Exit`, if any other thread (or your current code) tries to lock over the object with a non zero thread id, it will go into a spin wait or promote to a kernel based event if needed.

For what it's worth, since you have no care for reordering, and depending on what your use cases are, there are likely other [synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) that might be a better fit for your particular use case. Like a reset event etc.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if there's a better synchronization option. `AddListener` needs normal locking behavior while `_value` is unset, and even if there are 100 threads contending that lock in `AddListener`, `Execute` really only needs to wait for the current holder to exit, then all others could abort the lock. Do you think one of those other options would be better suited for that?