# Can compiler optimize away locks accessible to only one thread?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking, compiler-optimization

C# provides reentrant locking:

```cs
lock (obj) { ... }
```

Can the current C# compiler deduce, from context, that only one thread will ever have access to `obj` and therefore optimize away all (reentrant) locking statements on `obj`?

Related: [C# Does an empty lock block get "optimized" away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65976693/c-sharp-does-an-empty-lock-block-get-optimized-away)

More generally, do modern compilers build static models about threads? As humans we can statically check and conclude that e.g. "There will only be three threads at runtime: the UI thread, the network thread, and the animation thread". After that, it's also statically checkable which fields each thread has access to. From there we can compute a set of fields accessible to no more than one thread. Reentrant locking statements on those fields can then be safely removed. Can the current C# compiler do the above?

Maybe I'm stating the obvious, but I don't want to remove those locking statements in the source code. The actual number of threads depend on the environment configurations (decided before compiling), and I want the source code to be env-agonistic. Plus, with "extra" locking statements it's easier for the human to prove the correctness of the multi-thread program. In other words, ideally, program correctness should be locally checkable by the human; program efficiency should be globally optimizable by the compiler.

Comment: Unlikely. The code could be called by some other code that is not in the compiler's reach at this moment.

Comment: Why would you ever need this potential feature?  Why would you be locking on an object that you know is not accessible to any other thread, while also be a position where the cost of taking out an uncontested lock is an unacceptable performance cost?  If you think you need it, it sounds like you're designing your program wrong.

Comment: Have a read of this answer on the use of locks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384758/259769

Comment: I don't know about C#, but there are systems where, if the program provably has only one thread *total* (e.g. it never calls any library function that could start threads), then all locking functions become no-ops.  But deducing that a particular lock is only locked by one thread seems much too difficult a static analysis task. I expect the compiler, even if it tried, could only prove this in the most trivial of cases, which would not occur often enough in practice to be worth implementing the optimization.

Comment: The Linux kernel does something similar: when compiling, it generates a table with the addresses of all calls to lock functions.  At boot time, if it detects that it is running on a system with only one CPU, then it iterates over the table and replaces every such call instruction with `nop`.